# Error jack headers not found

Tags: command-line, 14.04, software-installation

Hello What command i need to fill and enter to fix this `configure` error:

Running 14.04 latest version of ubuntu

```
configure: error: JACK headers not found.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please, could you put some of your time to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the development packages required to build qtractor.

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libqt4-dev libjack-dev libsndfile1-dev libasound2-dev
```

On 14.04 I managed to properly configure qtractor, see my [logs](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7372410/).

Comment: libjack-dev Is already installed

Comment: Could you please mention what project you're trying to build or better a link to the project page so that we can look at the INSTALL/build instructions?

Comment: http://qtractor.sourceforge.net/qtractor-index.html

Comment: I'd need to know the ubuntu release you're running (13.10 or 14.04) and if you're building from svn trunk or the latest tar.gz

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 and latest targz

Comment: I've updated my answer after a 14.04 build test

Comment: Already installed all weird

Comment: Retested with in a clean 14.04 VM it works, I'd suggest to `sudo apt-get purge libjack-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libjack-dev`. The version should be the one of the [official repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libjack-dev). Make sure you don't interfere with possible PPA versions.

Comment: You can check your version with `dpkg -l | grep libjack-dev`